# How can I convert String() into Int() in Processing?

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I'm doing this project where I'm using an Arduino Board to read the heartbeat pulses, so I want to send from the Arduino to Processing only one number (the BPM of the person); so that I can use that information into my Processing code to manipulate some visual image that I have created in Processing.
My problem at the moment is that that information is in String(), so I can't use it as a  variable - Int() or float() - and  I'm having difficulties in making this conversion, from String to Int().

This is my code at the moment:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;

void setup () {
  size(600,600);
  noStroke();
  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; 
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);
} 
float t=0;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);

  if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,
  val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');  // read it and store it in val
  println(val);
  }

  translate(width/2, height/2);
  beginShape ();
  //add some vertices...
  for (float theta =0; theta <= 2*PI; theta += 0.01){
   float rad = r(theta,
     2, //a
     2, //b
     6, //m
     1, //n1
     cos(t)*0.9+0.7  , //n2
     sin(t)*0.9+0.7  //n3
     );

   float x = rad * cos(theta)*100;
   float y = rad * sin(theta)*100;
   vertex (x,y);
}
  endShape(CLOSE);
  t+=0.04;
}
float r(float theta, float a, float b, float m, float n1, float n2, float n3 ) {
  return pow(pow(abs(cos(m* theta/4.0) /a), n2) + pow(abs(sin(m* theta/4.0) /b), n3), -1.0/n1);
}
```

I have tried this to convert the String() to Int() but it doesn´t seem to work:

```
 Serial myPort;
   String val;
   int valInt;

 void draw ();
   if ( myPort.available() > 0)  {  
   val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         
   int valInt = Integer.parseInt(val);
   println(valInt);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `int()` function? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please edit your post.

Comment: @AndiCover Read the tag info <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That does not make the question more readable. The question is hard to read and that is all I am criticising.

Comment: @AndiCover I see your point.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I have tried to change it to int() function but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreiaPereira Can you please be more specific than saying it doesn't work? What does it do instead? What error do you see? Can you please post a [mcve] that we can run to see the problem ourselves?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, just post my current code and also what I tried to do to fix my problem. I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: @AndreiaPereira Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? What is the value of `val` before you try to convert it? What error are you getting?

Comment: @KevinWorkman before I try to convert it the programme runs fine, and I can see on my screen both of the image I code and the information that is coming from the Arduino. And I don't know how to answer what is the value of `val`.

Comment: @AndreiaPereira Did you read the link I just posted? You can debug your program using print statements or the Processing debugger.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, yes I have tried to use the Processing debugger, but I don´t know if I did anything wrong or if it is meant to take a long time because it didn't show me any results.

Comment: @AndreiaPereira To use the debugger, you need to set a breakpoint and then step through the code. Or you could add a print statement.

Answer (score 2):

In [Processing](https://processing.org/reference/) there is the built-in function [`int`](https://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html), which can convert a string (or a floating point value) to an integral number:

```java
String s = "123";
int x = int(s);
print(x);
```

Comment: My String is not just one "statement"; the values are always changing since the data is coming live from the Arduino board. Would it still work this example you just gave me?

Comment: @AndreiaPereira What do you mean by *"statement"* in this context. Do you've a variable which contains the string? If yes, then you can use  `int()` to convert the string to a integral number or [`float()`](https://processing.org/reference/floatconvert_.html), to convert to a floating point number. By the way, some code would improve your question.

Comment: I appolagize for the confusion I just edit my question with my code there.

Comment: What do you mean? Just by adding `int(val)` and then changing on the `myPort.readStringUntil('\n');`?

Comment: @AndreiaPereira `val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');` reads a string and stores the string in `val`. `int valInt = int(val);` converts the string to an integral value.

Comment: "NullPointerException" is the message that it gives me when I do that.

Comment: @AndreiaPereira You've to set `val` before `int(val)`. `String val;` is not initialized.

Comment: How can I fix it? Because the problem seems to be what you have said, about the `String val` not being initialised, but I don't know what to put as value for `val.`

Comment: @Pereira Init `val`, e.g.`String val = "";`. But why do you convert (`int(val)`) When nothig is assigned to it!?!? Init `intVal`, e.g. `int intVal = 0;` and chang it if you get a new  `val`

Comment: @Rabbit76, I have done that but it keeps saying "NullPointerException" because of this line     `int valInt = int(val) ;` , even after Init all.

Answer (score 0):

As Per mine understanding of your question, i have following solution
You can use following code to convert String value to int.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("51");
```

51 is string value which you can convert to int.

Comment: That's not the way to do this in [Processing](https://processing.org/reference/). In Processing there is the built-in function [`int()`](https://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html)

Comment: Hi Rabbid76 may i know what is meant by processing and int() function. I thought of program processing, is it something different?

Comment: Please read the tag info <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. The meaning of "processing" is not in a general way.

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76 to share

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "123";
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
println(i); // 123
```

Answer (score -1):

```
          String str="22";
          Int  value= Integer.valueOf(str);
```

Comment: My String is not just one "statement"; the values are always changing since the data is coming live from the Arduino board. Would it still work this example you just gave me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921049/reading-from-serial-port-gives-split-up-string